# Getting DateTime from MySQL table using C# and AllowZeroDatetime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am connecting to MySQL with C# using the AllowZeroDatetime option and when I query my table, it only works part of the way. The date I get back is all zeros but the time I get back is 12:00:00 AM. How do I fix this? Here is my connection string:

```
string connectionInfo =
@"server=" + @server +
@";userid=" + @username +
@";password=" + @password +
@";database=my_data;" +
@"AllowZeroDatetime=true;";
```

And here is the code I'm using to get the DateTime entries:

```
private static void getSelectGroups(MySqlConnection mysqlConn)
{
     String selectCommand = "SELECT user_date FROM my_table";

    // Set up table reader
    MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand(selectCommand, mysqlConn);
    MySqlDataReader dataRead = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dataRead.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dataRead["user_date"]);
    }
}
```

This is printing out 0/0/0000 12:00:00 AM. I need it to print 0/0/0000 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

The value `00/00/0000` isn't valid for a `DateTime` in .NET.  Years must be 1-9999, months must be 1-12, and days must be 1-N, where N is 28, 29, 30, or 31 depending on the month and year.

The MySql `AllowZeroDateTime` option works around this as described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html):

> If set to `True`, `MySqlDataReader.GetValue()` returns a `MySqlDateTime` object for date or datetime columns that have disallowed values, such as zero datetime values, and a `System.DateTime` object for valid values. If set to `False` (the default setting) it causes a `System.DateTime` object to be returned for all valid values and an exception to be thrown for disallowed values, such as zero datetime values.

So by setting it to `True`, you're getting back a `MySqlDateTime` object instead of a `DateTime` object.  Note that the docs are worded slightly incorrectly, as the implementation shows that a `MySqlDateTime` is *always* returned when `AllowZeroDateTime` is true (though you can still cast *valid* values to a `DateTime`).

Unfortunately, the `ToString` method on `MySqlDateTime` is not as robust as the same method on `DateTime`.  It has no overloads to change how it formats strings.  However, the *implementation* does use the current culture to format the string.

You have two options:

1. Implement new `ToString` extension methods
2. Change the current thread's culture settings so the existing `ToString` method will format with those settings.

Either will work, but I prefer option 1 because you don't have to worry about thread safety.  Here are extension methods that add the same overloads of `DateTime.ToString` to the `MySqlDateTime` object.

```
public static string ToString(this MySqlDateTime mdt, string format)
{
    return mdt.ToString(format, null);
}

public static string ToString(this MySqlDateTime mdt, string format, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return mdt.IsValidDateTime 
        ? mdt.GetDateTime().ToString(format, provider) 
        : new DateTime(1, 1, 1).ToString(format, provider).Replace('1', '0');
}
```

Place these in a static class, then you can call it like so:

```
MySqlDateTime mdt = (MySqlDateTime) dataRead["user_date"]
Console.WriteLine(mdt.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: This just gives me an error saying "Specified cast is not valid". I added the two methods to a static class and am calling them from a separate class.

Comment: This is with `AllowZeroDatetime=true` set?  It should work.

Comment: FYI - I just tested it and it works for me.  [See this GIST](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/548a4308dab8e52f5097).   I'm using MySql Server 5.6 and the MySql.Data 6.9.7 nuget package

Comment: That's the same way I used it. I have no idea why it's not working because it looks like it should. Oh well, I'll keep messing around with it.

Comment: Check your version of MySql.Data.  I'm using the latest available on Nuget.  Not sure if there was a behavior change in prior versions or not.

Comment: I re-downloaded the newest version from Nuget and it's still not working. It doesn't like the MySqlDateTime cast of the dataRead.

Comment: Try debugging and check the type of the object returned.  My guess is that it returns a `DateTime`, in which case the option might be misspelled in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Since `dataRead["user_date"]` returns `object`,  `Console.WriteLine(overload)` [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,497) as;

```
if (value == null) {
    WriteLine();
}
else {
    IFormattable f = value as IFormattable;
    if (f != null)
        WriteLine(f.ToString(null, FormatProvider));
    else
        WriteLine(value.ToString());
}
```

Since value is not `null` and `DateTime` implements [`IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, this line will be executed;

```
WriteLine(f.ToString(null, FormatProvider));
```

and this performs [The `"G"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) of your `CurrentCulture` which combinations of [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`LongTimePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) properties.

For your current culture, looks like this combinations performs as `d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format.

For the string representation that you want, you either use custom date and time formats or you can [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your `CurrentCulture` set it's `LongTimePattern` property to `HH:mm:ss` format that you need for `00:00:00` representation and use this culture.

```
Console.WriteLine(((DateTime)dataRead["user_date"]).ToString("d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

or

```
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
clone.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";

while (dataRead.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(((DateTime)dataRead["user_date"]).ToString(clone));
}
```

Comment: The only way I can get this solution to work is by adding `"Convert Zero DateTime = true;"` to the MySQL connection string, and it will allow the time to be  00:00:00, but the date is then switched to 01/01/0001.

Comment: This isn't a direct fix, but it works. I kept `AllowZeroDatetime=true` in the connection string and left out `Convert Zero Datetime = true`. In the while loop, I just added a simple if statement that checks if the date is the null date '0/0/0000 12:00:00 AM` and if so, will print off `0/0/0000 00:00:00

Comment: Close, but you missed the part about how the connection string parameter changes the return type of the object to a `MySqlDateTime`.  Nice attempt though. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson Argh, right. I assumed `MySqlDateTime` _perfectly_ mapped `DateTime` in .NET side. :(